# Have username and passphrase in OpenVPN client.conf?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, openvpn

With the `auth-user-pass filename` option is it possible to create a plain text file with username and passphrase.

Is it possible to have the username and passphrase directly in the client.conf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without recompiling `openvpn`. It's made this way to discourage putting them there.

If you want to have automatic VPN channel negotiation you really should use certificates and private keys. There should be an `easy-rsa` directory in documentation with scripts that will make it easier to set up single-purpose CA.

If you can't reconfigure the server (because you're not its administrator) then you really shouldn't keep your passwords in plain-text files...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to recompile openvpn. Take a look [here](http://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BuildingOnWindows) to build on Windows. It is always better to use certificates and private keys instead of plain text passwords